# SQL: Join two different rows from the same table to a relation

Tags: sql, oracle, join, subquery, where-clause

Let's say I've got a table called `relation` with these fields:

```
id, type, person1.id, person2.id
```

Then there's the table with the people called `person` with this field:

```
id, name
```

Now I want to create a list that contains the following information:

```
relation.id, relation.type, person1.id, person1.name, person2.id, person2.name
```

How can I achieve this with an SQL statement? I know that this is probably a pretty basic question. :-(

Comment: I don't understand you, show full the table structures with their types.

Comment: What's the key on table `person`? Is there another column beside `name`?

Comment: @wolφi Yes, there's an `id` on both tables. I've edited my question.

Comment: @HaroldL.Brown So where is the problem to write your own join of these two tables?

Comment: -1 is for your laziness, there is nothing to ask

Comment: @zaratustra I don't know how to you pull *two rows from the same table* to one relation.

Comment: @HaroldL.Brown for future questions read [this](http://tkyte.blogspot.de/2005/06/how-to-ask-questions.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the person table twice:

```
select rel.id, rel.type, p1.id, p1.name, p2.id, p2.name
  from relation rel
     , person p1
     , person p2
 where rel.person1 = p1.id
   and rel.person2 = p2.id
```

Take a look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Answer (score -1):

```
select relation.type,a.Person1_name,b.person2.name  from relation inner join 

(select relation.type, person1.name Person1_name from relation  inner join person
on relation.person1=person.name
where person1 is not null)a
on relation.type=a.type
inner join 
(
select relation.type, person2.name,from relation  inner join person
on relation.person2=person.name
where person2 is not null)b
on relation.type=a.type
```

pls try this code